# Use TableViewController inside SKScene

Tags: swift, uitableview, sprite-kit

I want a TableViewController to appear inside the scene whenever I click on a specific node as a small window. I created a TableViewController class to configure it. Here is my code inside SkScene:

```
        let table = Table()
        let smallerRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)
        let navRect = CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 200)
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table)
        nav.view.frame = navRect
        let frameView = UIView(frame: smallerRect)

        frameView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        table.view.frame = smallerRect
        frameView.addSubview(nav.view)
        self.view.addSubview(frameView)
```

Table class:

```
import UIKit

class Table: UITableViewController {

    var names = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 }
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }


 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

The problem is that the UIView that supposed to contain the tableview appears, but the table itself doesn't. 
I would appreciate any help or even if someone has a better way of achieving what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting your navViews/tableview frame based on the ***bounds*** of your frameView.

Which would be (0, 0, 200, 200). What's happening at the moment is that when your table gets added as a subview of your frame view, it is offset by 100. So it's drawn outside your frame views bounds.

Something like this maybe.

```
    let table = Table()
    let smallerRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)
    let navRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table)
    nav.view.frame = navRect

    let frameView = UIView(frame: smallerRect)
    frameView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    table.view.frame = frameView.bounds

    frameView.addSubview(nav.view)
    self.view.addSubview(frameView)
```

Hard to know where else to go with this without your `Table` code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not it, I updated my question with the Table class.

Comment: Would love to see a more complete SKScene impl. example in this answer :)